# Hiding Rows that don't display any of three certain values

Tags: excel, vba

I have some very basic VBA code here

```
sub HideRows_Based_On_Values

    For Each cell in Range (C12:AG37)
        if cell.value = "SD" or "SA" or "SN" then cell.entirerow.hidden = false
        else cell.entirerow.hidden = true
    next cell

End Sub
```

The range is correct, the inputs in the cells are correct.

For some reason, excel is hiding some (not all) of the rows that have at least one of these values present in them.  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I expected for the code to filter out any rows that don't have one of SD, SA, or SN present - but it's only working on some of the rows and not all.

Comment: please show your data, and which row is not working as it should.May there be any special characters or a space in on of the cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not:

```
A = 1 OR 2 OR 3
```

But:

```
(A = 1) OR (A = 2) OR (A = 3)
```

This is true in every computer program, computer programming language, ...

I've been testing until it worked and this is what I came up with:

```
Sub HideRows_Based_On_Values()

    For Each cell In Range("C12:AG37")
        If ((cell.Value = "SD") Or (cell.Value = "SA") Or (cell.Value = "SN")) Then
          cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else: cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

The weird part is that, next to the range where you need double quotes (`Range("C12:AG37")`), you need to put the action of the `Then` on the next line, otherwise it won't work.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

**Edit:**
Hereby the solution, as provided by the author of the question:

```
Sub HideRows_Based_On_Values()
  For Each Row In Range("C12:AG37").Rows
    If Application.CountIf(Row, "SD") + Application.CountIf(Row, "SA") + Application.CountIf(Row, "SN") = 0 Then 
    Row.Hidden = True
    Else Row.Hidden = False 
    End If 
  Next Row 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate you replying. For some reason, this still doesn't work how I would like it to. It still filters out some rows that are meant to remain. If I modify the range in the macro to target the rows that are supposed to be filtered out in the original range, it works - but with the larger range - it doesn't? Any ideas.

Comment: @pointbleak: I've edited my answer, apparently you can't put anything behind the `then` on the same line.

Comment: Thanks @dominique.  My desired state is for row 15 in your example to still show.  I think it's not working because it's flipping back to true when it checks cells after one of the values is present.

Comment: I have figured it out - 
Sub HideRows_Based_On_Values()
    For Each Row In Range("C12:AG37").Rows
        If Application.CountIf(Row, "SD") + Application.CountIf(Row, "SA") + Application.CountIf(Row, "SN") = 0 Then
            Row.Hidden = True
        Else
            Row.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next Row
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

```
sub HideRows_Based_On_Values

    For Each cell in Range (C12:AG37)
        if cell.value = "SD" OR cell.value = "SA" OR cell.value = "SN" then
            cell.entirerow.hidden = false
        else
            cell.entirerow.hidden = true
        end if
    next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you.  Appreciate you replying.  For some reason, this still doesn't work how I would like it to.  It still filters out some rows that are meant to remain.  If I modify the range in the macro to target the rows that are supposed to be filtered out in the original range, it works - but with the larger range - it doesn't?  Any ideas.